# How to access parent class's data member from child class, when both parent and child have the same name for the dat member

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, public

my scenario is as follows::

```
class Parent
{
public:
int x;
}

class Child:public Parent
{
int x; // Same name as Parent's "x".

void Func()
{
   this.x = Parent::x;  // HOW should I access Parents "x".  
}
}
```

Here how to access Parent's "X" from a member function of Child.

Comment: `x = Parent::x;` would be suffcient

Comment: And, as an added bonus, data hiding in this manner makes the code much less readable, less maintainable, and can introduce subtle bugs that are almost impossible to track down!  Huzzah!

Comment: As @Chad mentioned, this will have many issues involved. For learning and understanding these concepts, it is perfectly good to name them like that - but in real code, you should never do it like that. Also, `this` is a pointer, and pointer must be use with `->`, or `(*pointer)` notation.

Answer (score 14):

Almost got it:

```
this->x = Parent::x;
```

`this` is a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing it via the scope resolution operator will work:

```
x = Parent::x;
```

However, I would question in what circumstances you want to do this.  Your example uses public inheritance which models an "is-a" relationship.  So, if you have objects that meet this criteria, but have the same members with different values and/or different meanings then this "is-a" relationship is misleading.  There may be some fringe circumstances where this is appropriate, but I would state that they are definitely the exceptions to the rule.  Whenever you find yourself doing this, think long and hard about *why*.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a brief explaination of solutions provided by Luchian Grigore and Mr. Anubis, so if you are curious 'how this works', you should read it further.

C++ provides a so-called, "scope operator" (`::`), which is perfectly suited to your task.

More details are provided at [this page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05cplr175.htm). You can combine this operator with class name (`Parent`) to access parent's `x` variable.