# How to access the value of another class in current working class

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwidget, qdialog

Parent class : parentClass.h

```
class parentClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QString nextFollowUpDate;   //I want to access this variable from child class

}
```

Parent class : parentClass.cpp

```
// accessing child 

childClass*objcalender = new childClass();
objcalender->show();
```

Child class : childClass.h

```
class childClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    childClass();
}
```

Child class : childClass.cpp

```
#include parentClass .h

parentClass *myFollowUp = qobject_cast<parentClass*>(parent());

//object of myFollowUp is not created and program get terminated by showing exception 

parentClass->nextFollowUpDate = selectedDate;   //can not access this variable
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: childClass does not inherit parentClass! if you want to access the value in parentClass you should create an instance of that class.

Comment: i have included #include parentClass in child class

Comment: double question?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525418/how-to-access-parent-classs-data-member-from-child-class-when-both-parent-and

Comment: unless you make your 'nextFollowUpDate' static so you can access it parentClass::nextFollowUpDate

Comment: including class header, doesn't mean you inherit from it!!!

Comment: child class all-ready inherited  class childClass: public QWidget       can i make it as   class childClass:public Qwidget, public parentClass  (using multiple inheritance).

Comment: why use multiple inheritance! parentClass is already a QWidget.

Comment: can you give me line of code for better understanding

Comment: if we create object like this  parentClass *myFollowUp = new parentClass then it will call the parent class constructor but does not want this. i want to access parent class variable without calling constructor of parentClass

Comment: @basslo, how do you know that the asker want to inherit? and where do you see the multiple inheritance? i think the question is not about inheritance.

Comment: You may want to use signals and slots for this instead.

Comment: @drescherjm, can you give me line of code for better understanding

Comment: I don't fully follow what you are trying to do. I was just pointing out that in a lot of cases when using Qt you don't share variables between objects. You use signals and slots where one object signals that a variable has changed its value and then connect that to slots in other classes that do something when the value changes. If the value does not change after the objects exist you may want a different approach.

Comment: @sddk : it is just the classes names parentclass and childclass. But anyway i already answered it is either : create an instance of parentClass to access the member, or make this member static so no need for an instance. Even if i find that kind of design weird (where member are public)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.
First, if you want to access a member function or variable of class from another class you have to create an object of the class you want to acess and then just use "->" or "." to access it.
Something like this:

```
ParentClass* parentObjPtr = new ParentClass(); //not mandatory to use the new() operator, but it has always better to reserve the memory space
parentObjPtr->varName = "hello";
//OR
ParentClass parentObj = new ParentClass();
parentObj.functionName = "hello";
```

But if for some reason you don't plan on creating objects of that class, you can always make the members you want to access "static":

```
class parentClass: public QWidget
{

Q_OBJECT

public:

static QString nextFollowUpDate;

}
```

And then do this to access that member variable:

```
ParentClass::nextFollowUpDate = "hello";
cout << "Content of nextFollowUpDate: " << ParentClass::nextFollowUpdate << endl;
```

Also, if you plan on using that class a lot but dont want to keep typing "ParentClass::" in your code, you can define a namespace for that class next to your includes:

```
#include "ParentClass.h"
using namespace ParentClass;
----ETC----
----ETC----

int main(){
nextFollowUpDate = "hello"; //because we defined a namespace for that class you can ommit the "ParentClass::"
cout<<nextFollowUpDate<<endl;
}
```